# fixing an eslint error - Calls to require() should use string literals

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am correcting some errors which are eslint related and I am getting the following errors:

[image]

```
const requireFiles = (directory, app) => {
   fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(fileName => {
  if (fs.lstatSync(`${directory}/${fileName}`).isDirectory()) {
  requireFiles(`${directory}/${fileName}`, app);
  return;
  }
  // Skip this file
  if (fileName === 'index.js' && directory === __dirname) return;
  // Skip unknown filetypes
  if (validFileTypes.indexOf(fileName.split('.').pop()) === -1) return;
  // Require the file.
  const path = `${directory}/${fileName}`;
  const module = require(path).default;
  global.logger.logInfo('-requiring : ', path);
  if (module.init) {
     module.init(app);
     global.logger.logInfo('-initing : ', path);
    }
 });
};
```

How I understand this it is asking for a string but I creating this in the line above, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

> How I understand this it is asking for a string but I creating this in the line above

A string is not a string *literal*. A string *literal* is an expression starting with `"` or `'` and ending with a matching one of those, `"like this"` `'or this'`. You're using strings with `require`, but not string literals. The point of the restriction is that string *literals* can be statically analyzed. Strings created dynamically can't be.

If you want to use strings created dynamically (like the ones in the code you've shown), you'll have to turn off that ESLint rule. Using dynamic strings with `require` is fine in (say) Node.js. It's a problem when you're trying to use bundlers like Webpack or Rollup (because they need to statically analyze the module structure)l.

Comment: This is in node.js, do I need to change the eslintrc file to reflect this?

Comment: @Ropenfold - If you want to use dynamic strings with `require`, yes. See the ESLint documentation for details.